# Stash, Conditionals, and a Custom Field

Tags: stash, conditionals

New to Stash and here is what I'm trying to accomplish.  But so far, no such luck.

I have two templates - manage-social-media.html and .layout-account.html

Manage-social-media.html
Here I am gathering all of my content to pass to the layout-account template.  I am using Zoo Visitor, and I have a custom field for “Permissions” (cf_member_firm_permissions) that I’d like to check to see if they can edit their content, or view only.  So the custom field (Fieldpack - Dropdown) looks like this:

... : Select One
read-only : Read Only
editor : Editor

What I want to do is test that variable to see what it is, then set some stash variables accordingly.  Mainly, if they are read-only, I’d like to do the following:

Set Stash variable for:  “Read Only Message” - To tell them why they are unable to edit, and who they can contact.
Set Stash variable for:  “Disalbe form” - I was thinking that I would just add the stash variable (i.e. “disable” to the form fields so they could read them but not edit.  Any other suggestions?

So I got the value for {cf_member_firm_permissions} by doing the following:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details} 
    {cf_member_firm_permissions}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

From there, I can’t get it to work.  I’ve tried wrapping the above in a “stash”, wrapping the above around a “stash”, using a switchee statement to test the value of {cf_member_firm_permissions}, using a switchee statement to test the value of stash:user_permissions (after I’ve set it).  I can’t get anything to do what I want.

Of course, all of the above is set within a stash variable “main_content” which is pulled into the layout template.

Here is some of the code that I've tried:

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
    {exp:switchee variable="{cf_member_firm_permissions}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="read-only"}
        <h3>Hello Reader Permissions</h3>
        {exp:stash:set name="permissions"} disabled{/exp:stash:set}

        {/case}

        {case value="editor"}
        <h3>Hello Editor Permissions</h3>
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

It displays "Hello Reader Permissions", but won't display anything else.

Comment: Probably need to see more of your code. Make sure you have parse_tags="yes" and parse_depth params added to your stash set tag. Your stash might not be parsing the zoo tag. Does your main_content var pull anything into layout-account?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  My main_content var pulls the other content, that is basic channel entries stuff.  I was even trying to just post the values of the stash variables and that wasn't working.  My code has changed so many times that I'll have to run a few more tests and repost.  I was using parse_tags="yes", but not the parse_depth (wasn't aware of that).  I will try that and see.  Is it better to wrap the stash around the {exp:zoo_visitor:details}, or the other way around?

Comment: What about rethinking your approach a bit, and using switchee just output the form in the case of an editor, and output form values (minus the form) in the case of read-only? Or is your form on the layout template?

Comment: Where are you getting the permissions variable (I can see where it's set, but there's no get tag)?

Comment: @Tyssen I didn't include that but it was right below.  I used both a {exp:stash:get name="permissions"} and {exp:stash:permissions} - neither of them worked.

Comment: @Romans-8---31-39 - I think apparently I was trying to be "smarter" than that, and rather than output the information twice I was going to just assign a "disabled" to the form fields.  But in re-thinking it, it may just be smartest to do as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
     {exp:stash:set name="permissions"}{cf_member_firm_permissions}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

Then this is below

```
{exp:stash:main_content}
    {exp:switchee variable="stash:permissions" parse="inward"}
       {case value="editor"}
         Do this....
         My editable form
       {/case}
       {case value="read-only"}
         Do this....
         My read-only form
       {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
{/exp:stash:main_content}
```

Everything seems to be working with this set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting and getting in the same template, I think you need [`{exp:stash:parse}`](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aparse%7D).